# Pattern for characters that might be in the string

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I understand that I should be using `string.match()` to do this but I am having trouble matching characters that "might" be in the string, for example:

```
teststring = "right_RT_12"
```

I can easily do something like:

```
string.match(teststring , 'righteye_RT_[0-9]+')
```

This is fine if there is always "_[0-9]+ on the end of the test string, but there might be an instance where there are no digits on the end. How would I cater for that in Lua?

In Python I could do something like:

```
re.search("righteye_RT(_[0-9]+)?", teststring)
```

I thought something like this would work:

```
string.match(teststring, 'righteye_RT_?[0-9]+?')
```

but it did not. the result = `nil`

However, the following does work, but only finds the 1st digit:

```
string.match(teststring, 'righteye_RT_?[0-9]?')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string.match(teststring, 'righteye_RT_?%d*$')
```

Note the end-of-string anchor `$`. Without it, `%d*` matches the empty string and so the whole pattern would match things like `righteye_RT_junk`.

Comment: This works, thanks! But why does this work and %d+? does not? I thought the $ just searches for characters at the end of the string?

Comment: `%d+` does not work because it requires at least *one* digit.

Comment: I see, so %d* will work as well, but the ? was throwing it off as %d*? still does not work.

Comment: @iGwok But be carefull. That pattern matchs `righteye_RT_`string, wich may not be apropriate.

Comment: it does match "righteye_RT_" but also matches "righteye_RT" because of the ?

Answer (score 3):

`?` can be used only on one character in Lua pattern. You can use `or` to match two patterns:

```
local result  = string.match(teststring , 'righteye_RT_%d+') 
             or string.match(teststring , 'righteye_RT')
```

Note that `or` operator is short-circuit. So it try to match the first pattern first, if and only if it fails (returns `nil`), it would try to match the second pattern.

Comment: I like this. Is it not possible to do this in 1 line like in python's regular expressions: "(righteye_RT_%d+ | righteye_RT)"

Comment: @iGwok Lua pattern doesn't support `|`, so no, at least not like that.